# Space opera book about a group of adventurers

Tags: story-identification

It consisted of three or four stories, I remember one story: on a planet where the biggest casino is located a monster appears every night, and kills(steals?) one person. In this story main character is not the leader of the group, but a guy who was locksmith and hacker and spent a lot of time in casinos when he was younger. I read this in ~2000-2005, but the book is from ~80s I think.

Comment: The setup rings a bell: what about the other characters in the group of adventurers? Any memories on the other stories?

Comment: Very little. In first story their leader was captured by aliens and escaped something like prison. I think he also piloted some trading spaceships, but I'm not sure about this. Also aforementioned guy(locksmith) always tried to bamboozle other members because he didn't want to go back to jail, so he tried to hide after mission was complete, but I'm not sure about this also.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51005/a-book-featuring-the-superweapon-akka (about the first story in the series)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[**Three From The Legion**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?39624) by Jack Williamson (1979)

The third story is "One Against The Legion". In the casino space station, the villain makes good his threat to kill the top winner, each night. He uses a teleportation machine. The Legion sends their top team, including Giles Habibula, master lockpick and former con man. The casino was created by an old acquaintance of Giles, indeed many of the cheats in the gambling machine were invented by Giles.

When Giles tries to thwart the villain, the winner is kidnapped, and a large monster is left in his place.

The leader was a member of the Legion, who was framed by the villain years ago. Leader escapes prison and travels space in an attempt to clear his name.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is a little bit misleading.  Three From the Legion contains three novels and one novelette with characters from the Legion of Space series.  The copyright dates are listed as 1947, 1950, 1950, and 1967.   So One Against the Legion was first published 29 years, a generation, before 1979.

Comment: Whoa! That is a grell!